# Why can't I make an array of structs with bitfield?

Tags: arrays, c, c99, unions, bit-fields

Edit: I had to use union for that purpose specifically, because the chapter is about them. The fragment of the first task which the one I speak of is based on:

> Design a union named byte_set, which allows you to break up a number of type int so that all its component bytes can be displayed. The size of the union must be equal to the size of the int type, while the number of fields of the byte_set union must not exceed two.
>
> Include the union declarations in the byte_set.h file.
>
> Test its operation for an int number with the value 0x41424344 by displaying the values of its consecutive bytes.

I'm currently learning about **unions in C99**.

My task was this:

> Read an int by user, and then display it as:
>
> - 2x word
> - 4x bytes
> - 4x 8 bits (4 octets from Most Significant Bit, to Least Significant Bit)
>
> With the following restrictions:
>
> - without using bitwise operators,
> - without using `[]` operator to read arrays,
> - using only one `if` (ternary op. is forbidden).

My solution passes the tests fine, but I wanted to ask if there is any way to make it more compact in displaying the bit values.

My solution was this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct byte{
    unsigned char bit0:1;
    unsigned char bit1:1;
    unsigned char bit2:1;
    unsigned char bit3:1;
    unsigned char bit4:1;
    unsigned char bit5:1;
    unsigned char bit6:1;
    unsigned char bit7:1;
};

union bit_set{
    unsigned int number;
    unsigned short word[2];
    unsigned char byte[4];
    struct byte bytes[4];
};

int main() {
    union bit_set bit_set = {0};
    setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0);
    printf("Podaj liczbę: ");
    if(!scanf("%u", &bit_set.number)){
        printf("Incorrect input");
        return 1;
    }
    printf("%u\n", bit_set.number);
    printf("%d %d\n", *bit_set.word, *(bit_set.word+1));
    printf("%d %d %d %d\n", *bit_set.byte, *(bit_set.byte+1), *(bit_set.byte+2), *(bit_set.byte+3));
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
        printf("%d", (bit_set.bytes+i)->bit7);
        printf("%d", (bit_set.bytes+i)->bit6);
        printf("%d", (bit_set.bytes+i)->bit5);
        printf("%d", (bit_set.bytes+i)->bit4);
        printf("%d", (bit_set.bytes+i)->bit3);
        printf("%d", (bit_set.bytes+i)->bit2);
        printf("%d", (bit_set.bytes+i)->bit1);
        printf("%d", (bit_set.bytes+i)->bit0);
        printf(" ");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

### My guess to make it more compact:

```
struct byte{
    unsigned char bit0:1;
};

union bit_set{
    unsigned int number;
    unsigned short word[2];
    unsigned char byte[4];
    struct byte bits[32];
};

// ...

   for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
        for (int j = 7; j > 0; j--) {
            printf("%d", (bit_set.bits+j)->bit0);
        }
        printf(" ");
    }
```

#### The "compact" code above does not produce any good results. For inputs:

```
Enter a number: 1
```

it produces:

```
1
1 0
1 0 0 0
0000000 0000000 0000000 0000000
```

### Example 2:

```
Enter a number: 2
```

it produces:

```
2
2 0
2 0 0 0
0000000 0000000 0000000 0000000
```

Comment: You've changed it to be 32bytes long in the second example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C, a `struct` object has a minimum size of 1 byte.

Therefore, in the code

```
struct byte{
    unsigned char bit0:1;
};

union bit_set{
    unsigned int number;
    unsigned short word[2];
    unsigned char byte[4];
    struct byte bits[32];
};
```

the member `bits` is an array of 32 elements of `struct byte`, in which each element has a size of 1 byte. The total size of that array is therefore 32 bytes. You seem to expect the size of the array to be 32 bits, i.e. 4 bytes.

Comment: Additionally, bit-fields are not “separate” objects; they are inside some sort of container (one or more bytes) in a structure. The compiler manages that automatically so you do not see it directly, but it has effects.

Comment: Thank You all, now I understand, that indeed there's no other way it seems.

Comment: @lewando54 do not unions and bitfields at all

Answer (score 1):

Using bit-fields is not a good approach because the order of allocation within the union is not specified.  Furthermore, you cannot make arrays of bit-fields and the array of structures in your alternative solution is not an array of bits, is size is not even defined as the padding for each of the structures could be larger than 7 bits.

Using the `*(bit_set.byte+1)` to avoid the `[]` array syntax is fine. Alternately, you could use a pointer and increment it.

Here is a modified version, fully portable to exotic architectures:

```
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>

union bit_set {
    int number;
    unsigned short word[sizeof(int) / sizeof(unsigned short)];
    unsigned char byte[sizeof(int) / sizeof(unsigned char)];
};

#define countof(a)  (sizeof(a) / sizeof(*(a)))

int main(void) {
    union bit_set bit_set = { 0 };
    unsigned short *pw;
    unsigned char *pb;
    size_t i, n;

    printf("Enter a number: ");
    if (scanf("%d", &bit_set.number) != 1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cannot read number\n");
        return 1;
    }
    //printf("%u\n", bit_set.number); // not in the task

    pw = bit_set.word;
    for (i = 0, n = countof(bit_set.word); i < n; i++) {
        unsigned word = *pw++;
        printf("0x%04x%c", word, " \n"[i == n - 1]);
    }
    pb = bit_set.byte;
    for (i = 0, n = countof(bit_set.byte); i < n; i++) {
        unsigned byte = *pb++;
        printf("0x%02x%c", byte, " \n"[i == n - 1]);
    }
    pb = bit_set.byte;
    for (i = 0, n = countof(bit_set.byte); i < n; i++) {
        unsigned byte = *pb++;
        for (unsigned k = UCHAR_MAX / 2 + 1; k != 0; k /= 2) {
            printf("%u", byte / k % 2);
        }
        printf("%c", " \n"[i == n - 1]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Enter a number: 1234
0x04d2 0x0000
0xd2 0x04 0x00 0x00
11010010 00000100 00000000 00000000
```

Comment: @AndreasWenzel: fixed: `mask` should have been `k`... thanks for proof reading.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel: fixed, compiled and run.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel: not intentional, just lack of sleep I suppose...

Answer (score -1):

You do not need any unions and bitfields for that:

```
void print(unsigned int x)
{
    unsigned int y = x;
    printf("0x%08X\n", x);
    printf("0x%04X 0x%04X\n", (x % (USHRT_MAX + 1)), (x / (USHRT_MAX + 1)));
    for(size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(x); i++)
    {
        printf("0x%02X ", x % (UCHAR_MAX + 1));
        x /= (UCHAR_MAX + 1);
    }
    printf("\n");
    for(size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(x) * CHAR_BIT; i++)
    {
        printf("%x%s", y % 2, (i + 1) % CHAR_BIT ? "" : " ");
        y /= 2;
    }
}



int main(void)
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    for(int x = 0; x < 10; x++)
    {
        print(rand());
        printf("\n-----------------------\n");
    }
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/v3jW1bofs